# Do I have to check READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE before unzip obb file?

Tags: android, android-permissions, file-permissions

I want to unzip `obb` file to `getExternalFilesDir()` once the app was launched by the user (apk is built with `minSdkVersion 16`). I think to show runtime check permission to the user just when the app was launched is a bad experience.
Could you tell me whether I need to check permission before just unzip obb file.

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` is irrelevant; what's the `targetSdkVersion`? Besides, unzipping means writing, not reading.

Comment: targetSdkVersion 28 .I have test unzip obb file to getExternalFilesDir() (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.learn.test/files) without check permission on  Android os 7,9  . No exception was throw. But I don't test under Android os 6 .

Comment: You've likely once granted the permission already, which is required since Android 6.0, API 23.

Comment: When install my apk with Android os 7 and 9 and 5.1 ,there is no permission show to ask me  to granted .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any permission for getExternalFilesDir().

Not in manifest.

Not at run time.

Not for any Android version.

Comment: both unzip obb dir (<shared-storage>/Android/obb/<package-name>/) [obb dir link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files) to  getExternalFilesDir()
no need permission check ?

Comment: Mmmm.. /obb/ is a different path. Does not have much to do with getExternalFilesDir(). I think you need to request permission for it. But try and you will know.

Comment: I almost test some adnroid device ,which os is 5.1,7,8,9 . There is no exception was thrown when i just unzip with  /obb .So I think maybe unzip operation  is not relatied with read or write permission .